POSTFIX: no sasl connection cant find auth file
I'm using Ubuntu and postfix and dovecot to host a mail server. When i try and run telnet localhost 25 i get an error SASL no authentication methods. I am also using mysql to store usernames and passwords. The permissions for the auth file are correct.
My postfix config:
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 3.6
debug_peer_level = 3
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
default_transport = error
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, UbuntuDovecot, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = UbuntuDovecot.seattleschools.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_transport = error
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 4
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-mail-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox.cf


my dovecot config:
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-debug.log
disable_plaintext_auth = no
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_gid = vmail
mail_home = /var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_uid = vmail
namespace inbox {
    inbox = yes
    location =
    mailbox Drafts {
        special_use = \Drafts
    }
    mailbox Junk {
        special_use = \Junk
    }
    mailbox Sent {
        special_use = \Sent
    }
    mailbox "Sent Messages" {
        special_use = \Sent
    }
    mailbox Trash {
        special_use = \Trash
    }
    prefix =
}
passdb {
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
userdb {
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
service auth {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
        group = postfix
        mode = 0660
        user = postfix
    }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
verbose_proctitle = yes
verbose_ssl = yes


idk why it isn't working ive spent 12 hours trying to fix this. I use the SQL for user management It could be part of the problem idk.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.
